# componentes controlados y no controlados en react

Tags: reactjs

tengo un problema que me esta volviendo loco, estoy usando un date picker de material.ui de react y me dice que el componente que estoy usando es controlado, por lo tanto necesita un value y un onchangue, pero cuando estoy llenando algún campo en mi formulario me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me advierte que un componente controlado no puede pasar de controlado a no controlado, pero estoy usando un componente controlado y en ningún momento dejo de controlarlo, no entiendo por que debe ser, les dejo mi tsx:

```
import { KeyboardDatePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';

 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
       <KeyboardDatePicker
          className="input-register-date"
          clearable
          value={this.state.user.birth}
          placeholder="nacimiento"
          onChange={date => this.DateChangue(date)}
          minDate={new Date()}
          format="MM/dd/yyyy"
       />
 </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: De donde sale el `this.DateChangue` (sic) porque no se ve en tu código y si no está función en el scope pues ahí hay ya un problema.

Answer (score 0):

que valor tiene `this.state.user.birth` al inicio? creo que ese seria el problema, te sale ese error si es `undefined`. Podrias asignarle un valor por default.

```
state = {
   user: {
      birth: ''
   }
}
```

o algo asi:

```
 value={this.state.user.birth || ''}
```